# Pulling data out of nested JSON object when name of object is unknown

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm fetching data out of a mapping API (which returns JSON) and luckily for me as a JSON noob, the object I've been wanting to manipulate in the past has been named with a shortcut.

However, today I want to get data from an object which is named with a randomly generated number, which I won't know the name of when I fetch it. So I effectively want to write:

An example of the JSON is below. The data I am trying to access is the name of the Scottish Parliament constituency. So I am looking for an object which contains [type_name] = "Scottish Parliament constituency". I then want to look for the key/value pair within for name (in this example, Glasgow Kelvin).

In this case, the object has the randomly generated name of 134955, but if I don't know that beforehand, how I can write the javascript to scope within the find if it has that type_name, and therefore pull the name out? The objects aren't always the name number and order, so I can't just do it by saying "get the first object".

```
{
    "wgs84_lat": 55.861509653107056,
    "coordsyst": "G",
    "shortcuts": {
        "WMC": 14425,
        "ward": 151284,
        "council": 2579
    },
    "wgs84_lon": -4.246702245398941,
    "postcode": "G1 1BX",
    "easting": 259485,
    "areas": {
        "134955": {
            "parent_area": 148764,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 134955,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S16000117",
                "unit_id": "41386"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow Kelvin",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Scottish Parliament constituency",
            "generation_low": 15,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "SPC"
        },
        "2579": {
            "parent_area": null,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 2579,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S12000049",
                "local-authority-canonical": "GLG",
                "unit_id": "30631"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow City Council",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Unitary Authority",
            "generation_low": 36,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "UTA"
        },
        "151284": {
            "parent_area": 2579,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 151284,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S13002976",
                "unit_id": "43375"
            },
            "name": "Anderston/City/Yorkhill",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Unitary Authority ward (UTW)",
            "generation_low": 31,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "UTW"
        },
        "14425": {
            "parent_area": null,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 14425,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S14000029",
                "unit_id": "33920"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow Central",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "UK Parliament constituency",
            "generation_low": 2,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "WMC"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Object.values(data.areas)
  .filter(a=>a.type_name=="Scottish Parliament constituency")
  .map   (a=>a.name)
```

```js
const data={
    "wgs84_lat": 55.861509653107056,
    "coordsyst": "G",
    "shortcuts": {
        "WMC": 14425,
        "ward": 151284,
        "council": 2579
    },
    "wgs84_lon": -4.246702245398941,
    "postcode": "G1 1BX",
    "easting": 259485,
    "areas": {
        "134955": {
            "parent_area": 148764,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 134955,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S16000117",
                "unit_id": "41386"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow Kelvin",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Scottish Parliament constituency",
            "generation_low": 15,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "SPC"
        },
        "2579": {
            "parent_area": null,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 2579,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S12000049",
                "local-authority-canonical": "GLG",
                "unit_id": "30631"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow City Council",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Unitary Authority",
            "generation_low": 36,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "UTA"
        },
        "151284": {
            "parent_area": 2579,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 151284,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S13002976",
                "unit_id": "43375"
            },
            "name": "Anderston/City/Yorkhill",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Unitary Authority ward (UTW)",
            "generation_low": 31,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "UTW"
        },
        "14425": {
            "parent_area": null,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 14425,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S14000029",
                "unit_id": "33920"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow Central",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "UK Parliament constituency",
            "generation_low": 2,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "WMC"
        }
    }
 };
 console.log(Object.values(data.areas).filter(a=>a.type_name=="Scottish Parliament constituency").map(a=>a.name))
```

First you `.filter()` through all the `Object.values()` of `data.areas` for the `a.type_name=="Scottish Parliament constituency"` and then you apply a `.map()` to extract the `name` property from the filtered object(s).

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63942457/10102695), You can use "find" if you want to return once the first match occur!

```
const element = Object.keys(x.areas).find(item => x.areas[item].type_name === "Scottish Parliament constituency");

const obj = x.areas[element]; //Complete Object on matched type_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a recursive approach in order to get the object containing the value. After, you can use the object to get the desired value:

```js
var data = {
    "wgs84_lat": 55.861509653107056,
    "coordsyst": "G",
    "shortcuts": {
        "WMC": 14425,
        "ward": 151284,
        "council": 2579
    },
    "wgs84_lon": -4.246702245398941,
    "postcode": "G1 1BX",
    "easting": 259485,
    "areas": {
        "134955": {
            "parent_area": 148764,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 134955,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S16000117",
                "unit_id": "41386"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow Kelvin",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Scottish Parliament constituency",
            "generation_low": 15,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "SPC"
        },
        "2579": {
            "parent_area": null,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 2579,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S12000049",
                "local-authority-canonical": "GLG",
                "unit_id": "30631"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow City Council",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Unitary Authority",
            "generation_low": 36,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "UTA"
        },
        "151284": {
            "parent_area": 2579,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 151284,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S13002976",
                "unit_id": "43375"
            },
            "name": "Anderston/City/Yorkhill",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "Unitary Authority ward (UTW)",
            "generation_low": 31,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "UTW"
        },
        "14425": {
            "parent_area": null,
            "generation_high": 40,
            "all_names": {},
            "id": 14425,
            "codes": {
                "gss": "S14000029",
                "unit_id": "33920"
            },
            "name": "Glasgow Central",
            "country": "S",
            "type_name": "UK Parliament constituency",
            "generation_low": 2,
            "country_name": "Scotland",
            "type": "WMC"
        }
    }
};

function findEle(parent, data, val) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (typeof data == 'object') {
        var  eles = Object.entries(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
            if (typeof eles[i][1] == 'object') {
                var result = findEle(eles[i], eles[i][1], val);
                if (result != null) {
                    if (eles[i][1].hasOwnProperty('type_name')) {
                        return eles[i][1];
                    } else {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (eles[i][1] == val) {
                    return parent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var result = findEle(data, data, 'Scottish Parliament constituency');
console.log('Name is: ' + result.name);

console.log('---------------');

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```